# Vue Axios Request to php file

Tags: php, json, api, vue.js, axios

i try to send data (PersonName) from vue axios request to php script but git this error in php file :

> **Warning**:  Undefined array key "Person" in **C:\xampp\htdocs\linktree-vue\linktree-Create-Page.php** on line **7**
> null

i tried follwoing :

```
         const Pagedata = {
                Person: "Youmna",
            };

            const options = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost/linktree-vue/linktree-Create-Page.php',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                data: Pagedata
            };

            axios.request(options)
                .then(response => {
                
                    console.log(response.data);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error(error);
                });
```

php file (linktree-Create-Page.php) :

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080");
// Allow any domain to access the API
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$PersonName = $_POST['Person'];
print_r($PersonName);
echo json_encode($PersonName);
?>
```

Note : files pathes is correct, the request in f12 window is giving response 200 (success request) .. but doesnot read my data

Comment: did not understand . can u make it clearer, sur ?

Comment: To begin with, use `print_r($_POST)` then you can see exactly what php thinks is there in the POST data

Comment: But basically axios is sending the data as JSON, ignoring your header. You can see this is you use your browser's network tool to see the payload. Read the duplicate, it tells you what to do